# Display ProgressBar in Toolbar

Tags: android, material-design, toolbar, android-appcompat

I would like to show a ProgressBar during the update process at the bottom of the activity's toolbar. However, I still haven't found the right solution for it. How should I start?

I've already tried using a FrameLayout or putting the ProgressBar into the toolbar. Unfortunately, it never looked similar to these ones:

[image]

[image]

How to do something like this? My intention is that the layout doesn't change when the ProgressBar disappears.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try as follow on your xml layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

        <!-- Here your ProgressBar -->

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progress"
            android:layout_marginTop="-7dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="-7dp"
            android:indeterminate="true"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            style="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar.Horizontal" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        app:fabSize="normal"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

The result will be like this

[image]

Comment: I had to change android:layout_marginTop and android:layout_marginBottom to "-9dp", so that the layout isn't changed when the progress bar disappears. But now it works as expected.

Comment: Excellent solution, also `marginTop` and `marginBottom` might need some adjustments depending on your setup to avoid cropping. Mine were -7dp for top and -6dp for bottom.

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer should suffice in most cases, but if you'd rather not deal with the padding values, you can wrap `ProgressIndicator` and `Toolbar`, so that `ProgressIndicator` sits on top of `Toolbar`.

```
<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.MyApp.AppBarOverlay">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:popupTheme="@style/Theme.MyApp.PopupOverlay" />

        <com.google.android.material.progressindicator.LinearProgressIndicator
            android:id="@+id/progress_indicator"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:indeterminate="true"
            app:hideAnimationBehavior="inward"
            app:indicatorColor="@color/colorSecondary"
            app:showAnimationBehavior="outward" />
    </FrameLayout>
</com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
```

The difference is, if `ProgressIndicator` is drawn on top of `Toolbar`, then the height of `AppBarLayout` stays same.

```
[With FrameLayout]                   [Without FrameLayout]
+-------------------+   ^            +-------------------+   ^
|                   |   |            |                   |   |
|                   |   |            |                   |   |
|                   | AppBarLayout   |                   |   |
+-------------------+   |            |                   | AppBarLayout
| ProgressIndicator |   |            |                   |   |
+-------------------+   V            +-------------------+   |
|                   |                | ProgressIndicator |   |
|                   |                +-------------------+   v
|                   |                |                   |
.                   .                .                   .
.                   .                .                   .
```

Comment: What a lovely drawing!